# How do I go straight to the dictionary result for a Spotlight search in OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, spotlight, dictionary

So when I search in Spotlight, is there a keyboard shortcut to go straight to the Dictionary result?

Answer (score 3):

After you have your search term entered in spotlight:

CMD+D - Open in dictionary

CMD+L - Show quick look (dictionary)

See other cool Spotlight shortcuts:

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20120920053130411

Answer (score 2):

I don't know know any way to do that, but I suggest two workarounds:

- Type `dic` in the spotlight search, press enter to open the application and then write the word
- If you select a word, you can press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> or double tap with three fingers  to show its definition (this only works with certain applications)

Comment: Actually typing dic in spotlight is what I am doing now. Not bad, but just typing the word and then some single keyboard shortcut for dictionary would be even better...

Answer (score 2):

Did you know you can hit <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> anywhere in Mac OS X and it will pop up a dictionary definition for whatever word is under the mouse pointer?

That might be a better solution for you than Cmd-Space, type word, select Dictionary.

Comment: Yes i am aware of that shortcut. But I rarely use it as it's a bit of a finger twister. Command-Space for spotlight i use all the time however, it's more like a conditioned reflex than a conscious thought which Command-Control-d is. Thanks anyway